# MongoDB connection failed, should I restart server or restart MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, database-connection, server

my computer is Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I am connecting to a server to run codes. I also use the mongo on this server. However, it suddenly closed and when I tried to connect to the mongo shell, it shows:

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.9
connecting to: test
2015-05-02T16:37:34.643+0200 warning: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2015-05-02T16:37:34.643+0200 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:146
exception: connect failed
```

So should I restart mongo or should I restart the server? I use ps command to see all progresses on the server under my account, which is:

```
   PID TTY          TIME CMD
107018 pts/16   00:00:00 ps
233611 pts/16   00:00:00 bash
```

Does that mean that I cannot restart the server?

Comment: Please add the output of `ps -ax`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems mongodb suddenly shut down.

use `sudo service mongodb restart`to restart mongodb.

if it does not work and it is a test machine/personal computer ,

restart the machine is a good choice.

in addition,`ps` only shows your own process,`sudo ps` shows all process.

Comment: thanks for your comment, but I have no sudo right. I am a student doing project and I am using the group's server